# What is causing the server disconnection while running my program?

Tags: java

I'm doing a project for a class where I need to create a board like the game Battleship. I need to make an 8 by 8 board with 1 five length ship, 1 four length ship, 2 three length ships, and 1 two length ship. Then I need to print it out. I have all the functions I need and my code is finished, but when I press run, it just does nothing until I get the message "Server disconnected. Press Run to reconnect." I'm using CodeHS if that means anything.

Edit: I found out the error might be caused by the way I'm trying to call createBoard(); in line 10. I'm not sure how I would call it correctly (I am very much a beginner), because every time I try it the way I know, I get a message that tells me I can't call a non-static method in a static context. I don't even know what that means.

Edit 2: I have changed all my methods to static methods, the program does the same thing it has been doing in the CodeHS IDE, and runs but doesm't output anything in a debugger.

Here's the program:

```
    public class Battleship
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Battleship();
    }
    
    public Battleship()
    {
        createBoard();
    }
    
    public int[][] board = new int[8][8];
    
    public void createBoard()
    {
        //fill board with 0's
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
            {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
         
        //fix loops to exec the right amount of times (FIXED)
        int startX = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
        int startY = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
        // size 5 ship
        while(shipDirection(startX, startY, 5) == -1)
        {
            startX = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
            startY = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 5) == 1)
        {
            for(int i = startX; i < startX + 5; i++)
            {
                board[startY][i] = 5;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 5) == 2)
        {
            for(int i = startX; i > startX - 5; i--)
            {
                board[startY][i] = 5;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 5) == 3)
        {
            for(int i = startY; i < startY + 5; i++)
            {
                board[i][startX] = 5;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 5) == 4)
        {
            for(int i = startY; i > startY - 5; i--)
            {
                board[i][startX] = 5;
            }
        }
        
        //size 4 ship
        while(shipDirection(startX, startY, 4) == -1)
        {
            startX = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
            startY = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 4) == 1)
        {
            for(int i = startX; i < startX + 4; i++)
            {
                board[startY][i] = 4;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 4) == 2)
        {
            for(int i = startX; i > startX - 4; i--)
            {
                board[startY][i] = 4;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 4) == 3)
        {
            for(int i = startY; i < startY + 4; i++)
            {
                board[i][startX] = 4;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 4) == 4)
        {
            for(int i = startY; i > startY - 4; i--)
            {
                board[i][startX] = 4;
            }
        }
        
        //size 3 ship
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            while(shipDirection(startX, startY, 3) == -1)
            {
                startX = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
                startY = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
            }
            if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 3) == 1)
            {
                for(int i = startX; i < startX + 3; i++)
                {
                    board[startY][i] = 3;
                }
            }
            if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 3) == 2)
            {
                for(int i = startX; i > startX - 3; i--)
                {
                    board[startY][i] = 3;
                }
            }
            if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 3) == 3)
            {
                for(int i = startY; i < startY + 3; i++)
                {
                    board[i][startX] = 3;
                }
            }
            if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 3) == 4)
            {
                for(int i = startY; i > startY - 3; i--)
                {
                    board[i][startX] = 3;
                }
            }
        }
        
        //size 2 ship
        while(shipDirection(startX, startY, 2) == -1)
        {
            startX = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
            startY = (int) Math.random() * 8 + 1;
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 2) == 1)
        {
            for(int i = startX; i < startX + 2; i++)
            {
                board[startY][i] = 2;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 2) == 2)
        {
            for(int i = startX; i > startX - 2; i--)
            {
                board[startY][i] = 2;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 2) == 3)
        {
            for(int i = startY; i < startY + 2; i++)
            {
                board[i][startX] = 2;
            }
        }
        if(shipDirection(startX, startY, 2) == 4)
        {
            for(int i = startY; i > startY - 2; i--)
            {
                board[i][startX] = 2;
            }
        }
            
        //printing the board
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
                System.out.println("");
        }
    }
            
    //check for battleship intersection (FIXED)
    public int shipDirection(int x, int y, int size)
    {
        if(x + size <= 8)
        {
            for(int i = x; i < x + size; i++)
            {
                if(board[y][i] != 0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }
        else if(x - size >= 0)
        {
            for(int i = x; i > x - size; i--)
            {
                if(board[y][i] != 0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return 2;
        }
        else if(y + size <= 8)
        {
            for(int i = y; i < y + size; i++)
            {
                if(board[i][x] != 0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return 3;
        }
        else if(y - size >= 0)
        {
            for(int i = y; i > y - size; i--)
            {
                if(board[i][x] != 0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return 4;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see if there is somewhere the code is getting stuck?

Comment: I have tried to use a debugger, but I couldn't figure it out. This class is my only experience with java, so I don't know much.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're actually encountering an infinite loop. I copy/pasted your code directly into the CodeHS IDE, and got the same thing. When I replaced the `while` statements with `if`, it executed normally.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped. I just have to make the program work as intended now haha.